# jQuery Sliding Animation Not Fully Disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this code:

```
$('#container').animate({ height: '-=400px'}, 1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

The container is 400 pixels in height, the goal being to try make it shrink out into nothing, but at the end of the animation the div is still there, about 5 pixels in height, it doesn't fully collapse on itself as you'd expect with an empty div with no height value.

I've tried making it `-=410px` but the result is the same, it doesn't fully disappear - i've tried adding the fadeOut animation but it's a bit clunky. Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: Found some stray padding which seemed to be causing the issue, now i'm having an issue with the border of the div disappearing afterwards.

Comment: Does this fiddle mimic your exact code? http://jsfiddle.net/mUYys/ The animation completes and the div is gone for me. Are you sure this happens in all browsers? Also, you can see in my demo (at least in some browsers) the content within the div hides last, does the content of your `#container` have some strict `display` rules associated with it?

Comment: @Dpeif - Thats odd, i tried your code and it works as expected, put my css in it's place, it still worked as expected - but not in my site, i'll post more code now as it seems its not the jQuery

Comment: Thanks, or a link to the page in question might work if it's publicly available, to inspect with firebug/devtools

Comment: @Dpeif - Found some stray padding, but I'm now having an issue with the border, if you add a border onto your jsfiddle its working the same as mine now - the content is hidden in mine so thats not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into the .animate() API for JQuery, and it looks like you're hardcoding the "toggle" target property. Try this:

```
$('#container').animate({ height: 'toggle'}, 1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

Comment: After adding a border, with a hardcoded height value, i could see the bug OP is describing. Using toggle, as in this demo, fixes the issue for me http://jsfiddle.net/mUYys/2/ good find. Perils of using a framework are quirks like these, but you can't get away from it sometimes.

Comment: I've added the toggle instead thanks! - but the border is still clunky at the end

Comment: @Dpeif - In your latest jsfiddle.net/mUYys/2 remove the text from the html and add: display:inline-block; to the CSS - thats happening on mine now, at the very last few pixels - the display animation seems to switch from going up the page, to going down the page - can u see what i mean?

Comment: I see that `inline-block` reverses the direction, because of the way the element sits in the DOM at that point. If you add `vertical-align: top;' this will work in most browsers (I think) to set the vertical direction of the animation correctly. However, i don't see the graphical bug i think you are talking about with the last few pixels, sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/mUYys/3/ here is the vertical-align solution.

Comment: @Dpeif - ah ha! that fixed the border issue as well! tyvm

Comment: Not a problem, if you get a chance please accept the answer from @johnfoley3 since it solves your original request, thanks